# Angular - formControlName

Tags: angular, angular-material

I do have this form (FormGroup) in my component:

```
public form: FormGroup; 
this.form = this.formBuilder.group({ 
 address: this.formBuilder.group({       
    country: ['', [Validators.minLength(2)]]
  })
});
```

and the template of this component looks like this:

```
<form [formGroup]="form" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <div formGroupName="address">
        <mat-form-field style="width:95%">
            <mat-select placeholder="Country" formControlName="country" (selectionChange)="countryOfAddressChanged(country)">
                <mat-option *ngFor="let countryType of countryTypes" [value]="countryType">
                    {{countryType | translate}}
                </mat-option>
            </mat-select>
        </mat-form-field>
    </div>
</form>
```

if I select a country - country is still undefined - so **formControlName="country"** does not work as attribute of  **- therefore the invokation of countryOfAddressChanged(country)** does not work because country is undefined. 
What do I have to do in order to get it work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
countryOfAddressChanged(country)
```

`country` is not defined anywhere, hence it'll be `undefined`. If you want to get the valuue of the form control `country`, you can obtain it by accessing it from the formgroup like `form.get('country').value`

```
<mat-select placeholder="Country" formControlName="country" (selectionChange)="countryOfAddressChanged(form.get('country').value)">
    <mat-option *ngFor="let countryType of countryTypes" [value]="countryType">
        {countryType | translate}}
     </mat-option>
</mat-select>
```